# cuda header inclusion fails

Tags: c++, cuda, compiler-errors

I want to build a cuda plugin for an other project written in C++ using MPI.
I got the following situation:

- startingpoint.cpp is a c++ file including the cudaintegrator.h and
  includes datastructure.h
- cudaintegrator.h is the header file for a
  cuda file including datastructure.h
- cudaintegrator.cpp is the
  implemenation of cudaintegrator.h
- datastructure.h is a header file
  specifing some datastructures

the files are organized like that:

```
/trunk/
   /src
      /folder1
         /folder2
            /startingpoint.cpp
         /folder3 
            /cudaintegrator.h
            /cudaintegrator.cpp
      /folder4
         /folder5
            /datastructure.h
```

When I run `nvcc` from my trunk dir  with the following command:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc   -c -o src/folder1/folder3/cudaintegrator.o src/folder1/folder3/cudaintegrator.cu
```

the included file `#include "folder4/folder5/datastructure.h" is not found:

```
src/folder1/folder2/cudaintegrator.h:12:33: fatal error: folder4/folder5/datastructure.h: No such file or directory
```

When I run `mpic++` for the compilation of `startingpoint.cpp`, which uses the same include, the `datastructure.h` is found.

I suspect that the working directory of nvcc and mpic++ are somehow different(?) even both are run from the trunk directory.
When I change the include to `../../folder4/folder5/datastructure.h` the file itself is found, but subsequent includes fail for the same reason. I can not change the includes in all subsequent files because they can't be found by `mpic++` in this case.
Does anyone have a suggestion how I should include the files in this situation correctly, or how to instruct `nvcc` to find the included files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing include paths (`-I`) to the nvcc invocation should be enough (if not, it uses relative include paths only, that's why adding `../..` works for a single include).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you said, i missed to add `-I./src` to my NVCC compiler options. How embarrassing... Thanks for helping!